# .bat to copy from a non-fixed path

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to copy from folder "N:\8\Installation Release\Current 8.18.310\Web" to my local "D:\Abc". 
The catch is that the name "Current 8.18.310" will be changing constantly, e.g. to "Current 8.18.410". So far i have come up with the below and it doesn't seem to work, it copies 1-2 files / folders but it just stops there. Please advise!!

```
For /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /S /B /AD "N:\8\Installation Release" ^| findstr /i "current" ^| findstr /i "web"') do (
xcopy "%%i"* /D /C /Q /R /Y /I /S "D:\Abc" & goto :eof
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %i in ('dir /B /AD "N:\8\Installation Release" ^|findstr /i current') do (
  xcopy "%%i\web\*" /D /C /Q /R /Y /I /S "D:\Abc"
)
```

We only really do a check for the folder containing `current` and then assign it to `%%i` token, then copy from the underlying `web` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [`for /D` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) here to resolve the changing directory, like this:

```cmd
for /D %%D in ("N:\8\Installation Release\Current *") do (
    xcopy /D /C /Q /R /Y /I /S "%%~D\Web\*.*" "D:\Abc"
)
```